# VPS specs and gaming dedicated servers

Tags: gaming, vps

Been thinking of launching some dedicated servers for a while now, using VPS:es. However I got some techinical questions about their specs and how much they would be able to handle.

Now let's say I want to host multiple Team Fortress 2 servers. Mostly I'm looking for to run custom gamemodes, that are, in my opinion, not so advanced. It could be one Saxton Hale server, One deathrun server and the last one would just be a normal CP server (like dustbowl for example). Now my question is, which of the specs below would run these 3 servers best? And would I even be able to run 4 servers (the 4th would also be a ctf server)?

1st VPS:
2 full cores (not given very much details about this), 2gb of ram and 8tb bandwidth.

2nd server:
2x3.2Ghz+ cores, 4GB RAM (6GB burstable) and 5tb bandwidth.

The bandwidth question is not really that important, i would use another host to handle all fastDL. But would it be any big difference in performance running these gamemodes on those specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second VPS server has the most resources available to it, therefore it would be the better option. *However none of the servers you listed will be able to run all three servers properly.*

---

**Insufficient CPU**

It should be noted that you might run into problems with only two CPU cores. Try to go for one CPU core per server (*so at least three CPU cores*).

VPSes are virtual servers, and thus you share resources. You will share resources with other virtual servers running on the physical machine, some providers guarantee a full CPU core (*such as in one of the VPSes you listed*), but not all do.

---

**Server Slots**

You'd be okay with 16 slots to each server on the second VPS, but any higher than that and you'd need more RAM; 4GB would be the limit for the servers you want to host.
Although the VPS will look like you have 6GB RAM (in the hardware specifications within the operating system), the extra 2GB RAM will only be available to you if the physical machine hosting the VPS has the resources to do so.

---

**Operating System**

You almost certainly want Linux, and most providers of VPSes will only support the use of Linux and not Windows, due to the *virtualizer* not supporting it. It is best to pick a popular Linux flavour, I personally use Ubuntu 14.04 on my own VPS.

---

I host a Minecraft server on a Platinum X8 server from Server4You; it is cheap but the service is very good.

The server has:

- 16 CPU cores;
- 18GB RAM (30GB Burst);
- 800GB HDD;
- 100Mbit connection

They also offer good deals on lower-specification VPSes.

Comment: What if I only host servers running sourcemod, few plugins and standard valve maps? Would it make any difference in performance in my case?

Comment: @P.Nick As Andy mentioned, you won't have enough resources to run all three servers above 24 slots, even if they're all vanilla.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I took a look at their VPSes and my budget is around 20 dollars. Would their Plus X8 VPS be good enough to run my wanted server? And how much bandwidth do you get per month? They dont say anything about that.

Comment: @P.Nick Yeah- it'll be more than enough. Their VPSes have unlimited bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, I dont have much knowledge about these things! How many 24 player servers do you think I would be able to run then, if they're custom gamemodes? I'm just a bit excited :)

Comment: @P.Nick I'd say around 14.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30832/discussion-between-p-nick-and-bob).